# Could you recommend me a good book on Islamic apologetics/fundamental theology?

Tags: prophets, revelation

As-salamu alaykum! I would like to ask you to recommend me a good book on Islamic apologetics/fundamental theology.
Especially, I would like to better understand the concept of Revelation and Prophethood and the proofs of the Prophethood of Muhammad (ﷺ), such as ’i‘jāz or Splitting of the Moon miracle; I have read something on it, but in a too scattered way, I would like to study this topic in a more thorough and systematic way.
Is there any good and thorough scholarly work on this topic in English or French? I would prefer scholarly, academic works.
Thank you very much for your recommendation.